# Find the Lagrange multipliers: $f(x,y,z)=x+xyz$ subject to constraint $g(x,y,z)=x/3+y/2+z/4 - C = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the Lagrange multipliers  $f(x,y,z)=x+xyz$ subject to constraint $g(x,y,z)=x/3+y/2+z/4 - c= 0$

Criteria: $x,y,z,c$ are positive integers, c is constant, and the constraints are $x≥0$, $y≥5$, $z≥50$, $c≥0$.

My attempt:
$$\langle f_x,f_y,f_z\rangle = λ\langle g_x,g_y,g_z\rangle$$
$$\langle 1+yz,xz,xy\rangle = λ\langle 1/3,1/2,1/4\rangle$$
$$3+3yz = 2xz = 4xy$$
$$2xz = 4xy \implies x = 0 \text{ or } z=2y$$

For $z=2y$,
$$3+3yz = 2xz$$
$$3+3y(2y) = 2x(2y)$$
$$6y^2 -4xy +3 = 0$$

What's next?

Comment: Don't forget the equation $g(x,y,z)=0$

Comment: $x,y,z,C$ are positive integers? Or positive reals?

Comment: positive integers

Comment: If they are positive integers, how can you differentiate the functions $f$ and $g$?